# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must supply a valid URL

Tags: java, jsoup, illegalargumentexception

Im trying to build a web crawler for my OOP class. The crawler needs to traverse 1000 wikipedia pages and collect the titles and words off the page. The current code I have will traverse a singular page and collect the required information but it also gives me the error code "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must supply a valid URL:" Here is my crawlers code. Ive been using Jsoups libraries.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class crawler {


   private static final int MAX_PAGES = 1000;

   private final HashSet<String> titles = new HashSet<>();

   private final HashSet<String> urlVisited = new HashSet<>();

   private final HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();


   public void getLinks(String startURL) {


       if ((titles.size() < MAX_PAGES) && !urlVisited.contains(startURL)) {


           urlVisited.add(startURL);

           try {

               Document doc = Jsoup.connect(startURL).get();
               Elements linksFromPage = doc.select("a[href]");

               String title = doc.select("title").first().text();

               titles.add(title);
               String text = doc.body().text();

               CountWords(text);

               for (Element link : linksFromPage) {

                   if(titles.size() <= MAX_PAGES) {


                       Thread.sleep(50);
                       getLinks(link.attr("a[href]"));
                   }
                   else {
                       System.out.println("URL couldn't visit");
                       System.out.println(startURL + ", " + urlVisited.size());
                   }

               }

           } catch (Exception e) {

               e.printStackTrace();

           }
       }

   }


   public void PrintAllTitles() {

       for (String t : titles) {
           System.out.println(t);
       }
   }


   public void PrintAllWordsAndCount() {

       for (String key : map.keySet()) {

           System.out.println(key + " : " + map.get(key));
       }
   }

   private void CountWords(String text) {

       String[] lines = text.split(" ");

       for (String word : lines) {

           if (map.containsKey(word)) {
               int val = map.get(word);
               val += 1;
               map.remove(word);
               map.put(word, val);
           } else {
               map.put(word, 1);
           }

       }
   }
}
```

The Driver function just uses c.getLinks(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer)
as the starting URL.

Comment: You may print startURL before Jsoup.connect(startURL).get() to see what you are trying to get. If a[href] is relative link (like path/without/server), it fails.

Comment: I printed startURL and the address was the URL that was being passed into the method. could the problem be with my cssQuery ( a[href] )

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in this line:

```java
getLinks(link.attr("a[href]"));
```

[`link.attr(attributeName)`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#attr(java.lang.String)) is a method for getting an element's attribute by name. But `a[href]` is a CSS selector. So that method call returns a blank String (as there is no attribute in the element named `a[href]`), which is not a valid URL, and so you get the validation exception.

Before you call `connect`, you should log the URL you are about to hit. That way you will see the error.

You should change the line to:

```java
getLinks(link.attr("abs:href"));
```

That will get the absolute URL pointed to by the `href` attribute. Most of the hrefs on that page are relative, so it's important to make them absolute before they are made into a URL for `connect()`.

You can see the URLs that the first `a[href]` selector will return [here](https://try.jsoup.org/%7EDdmneQtxwyD_kEw4S68WadVvvdU). You should also think about how to only fetch HTML pages and not images (e.g., maybe filter out by filetype).

There is more detail and examples of this area in the [Working with URLs](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/working-with-urls) article of jsoup.